# collapsing an accordion "li" when class is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to sort through this for a while now, can't seem to get it working 100%. The current code reveals the `.content` area without any collapse. It also shifts the page down to center on the content (which in this case goes under the fold if you don't).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vl-option .vl-toggle-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').find('.content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.vl-option').bind('click',function(){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            theOffset = $(self).offset();
            $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 20 });
        }, 310);
    });
});
```

I've attempted a few approaches to no avail. I'll list a few below (concept was to find any siblings and collapse):

```
$(this).siblings('li').find('.content').slideToggle();
```

which actually breaks the original functionality. Then I went with the following (to try an make anything without class="active" collapse):

```
if ( $(this).siblings('li').not('.active').find('.content').slideToggle(); ) //also tried .hide()
```

which doesn't seem to have any affect on anything.

The HTML is simple

```
<ul>
  <li class="lv-option active"><!-- when toggled, "active" class is applied... -->
    <a href="#" class="vl-toggle-link">Yada</a>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="lv-option"><!-- ...when untoggled, "active" class removed -->
    <a href="#" class="vl-toggle-link">Yada yada</a>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`.active` is only applied for stylistic reasons. it has no effect on the functionality of anything. Just needed to be able to target the `:before` / `:after` when something was selected.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around jquery... argh.

Comment: I wrote this plugin for exactly this purpose. It's super light weight and simple http://plugins.jquery.com/quiccordion/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'd usually build out an accordion using type="radio" and css for this, but I'm really trying to pick up jquery so went with it for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one content at a time should be opened in an accordion right, so applying `.slideToggle()` to all `<li>` contents will break this rule. I think it's okay with your markup since you only have two `<li>`, so they just slides alternately. But if you have more I think the active `<li>` only should be `.slideToggle()` other should be `.slideUp()` only.

You can just chain them all:

```
$('.vl-toggle-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //find the sibling content apply slideToggle, then move to their parent and add active
    $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle().parent('li').addClass('active')
    // go through all the siblings of their parent and remove active, then slideUp their child content
    .siblings('li').removeClass('active').children('.content').slideUp();    
});
```

I also find your `.animate({scrollTop})` not working properly because it's obtaining the old `offset().top` value. I think you should get the `offset().top` after the `slideToggle()` has finished. See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz7fk/).

Or you can also calculate scrollTop: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz7fk/1/).

Comment: This works great aside from the scrollTop scrolls the wrong direction, thanks for explaining the thought process behind chaining it, but I have a question. What is the benefit/disadvantage from using scrollTop vs. Offset().top?  Not criticizing either method, just grabbing for information because I don't know. The scrollTop fiddle actually has a reverse scroll than what I was going for. The offset().top fiddle works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see anything different with the direction. The difference between the two methods is that with `offset().top` we're animating the scrolling after the `slideToggle` is completed. The calculated `scrollTop` method on the other hand is fired simultaneously with the `slideToggle`.